# HpCISSs2 + \Device\Raidport0 issue

Tags: windows, raid, hp, hp-smart-array

For some time in my HP DL380 G8 I have struggling with the problem with HpCISSs2 which is provider of `\Device\Raidport0 was issued` problem.

In event logs this problem occurs many times per day. 
Result below:

```
> - System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  HpCISSs2 

  - EventID 129 

   [ Qualifiers]  32772 

   Level 3 

   Task 0 

   Keywords 0x80000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2018-10-04T08:59:35.361121400Z 

   EventRecordID 23422866 

   Channel System 

   Computer 

   Security 


- EventData 

   \Device\RaidPort0 
   0F001800010000000000000081000480040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000050000810004800000000000000000
```

I already update SPP to the newest,Array driver HpCISSs2 is up to date
 `Product Version: 6.28.0.64 PASS 6 (x64-W2K8).`

I thought it is problem connected with Raid Controller and I have already replace motherboard for a new one but... problem still occurs.

Maybe someone had that kind of issue and know how to solve it?

I'll be appreciate.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a similar issue in the past and uninstalling WBEM providers per this HPE advisory fixed the issue:

http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c04718464

Please note that the advisory references some antivirus products, however we had none.

Comment: Helpfully! Thank You, it solved my problem! Raidport message is gone!